# How to sort nested dict based on second value

Tags: python

I have a dict like this: (More than 1000 records)

```
{"Device1": [["Device1", "TenGigabitEthernet1/0/12", "SHUT", "", "", "IDF03"], ["Device1", "TenGigabitEthernet1/0/11", "SHUT", "", "", "IDF03", "#f76f6f"]], "Device2": [["Device2", "TenGigabitEthernet1/0/12", "SHUT", "", "", "IDF03"], ["Device2", "TenGigabitEthernet1/0/11", "SHUT", "", "", "IDF03", "#f76f6f"]]}
```

The problem is, I don't know how to sort the dict based on the portName which would be `TenGigabitEthernet1/0/*` or `GigabitEthernet1/0/*`

I have the following code but it's not doing it right:

```
with open("data-dic.txt", 'r') as dic:
    data = dic.read()
    dataDic = json.loads(data)
    dataDic = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(dataDic))

    d2 = OrderedDict({ k : dataDic[1] for k in natsorted(dataDic) })
    print(d2)
```

It is sorting the keys which is the Device1, Device2,...

How can I sort the dict based on the second value of the nested dict? which would be all the portNames.

Comment: For each key there is 2 port name available, which one will you use?

Comment: FYI, you can combine `dic.read()` and `json.loads(data)` into `json.load(dic)`

Comment: Why are you calling `ast.literal_eval()`? `dataDic` already contains the dictionary.

Comment: You don't need to use `OrderedDict`. Since python 3.8 dictionaries are guaranteed to maintain their insertion order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

header = ['Name', 'Connection', 'Type', 'Col_3', 'Col_4', 'ID', 'Color']

df = pd.DataFrame(chain(*data.values()), columns=header).fillna('')
print(df)
```

This looks like:

```
      Name                Connection  Type Col_3 Col_4     ID    Color
0  Device1  TenGigabitEthernet1/0/12  SHUT              IDF03
1  Device1  TenGigabitEthernet1/0/11  SHUT              IDF03  #f76f6f
2  Device2  TenGigabitEthernet1/0/12  SHUT              IDF03
3  Device2  TenGigabitEthernet1/0/11  SHUT              IDF03  #f76f6f
```

Overkill for this issue... but if you are going to be doing other manipulation of this data, you may want to consider `pandas`.

```
df['Port'] = df.Connection.str.extract('.*/(.*)').astype(int)

out = (df.sort_values('Port')
         .drop('Port', axis=1)
         .groupby('Name', sort=False)
         .apply(lambda x: x.apply(list, axis=1).tolist())
         .to_dict())

print(out)
```

Output:

```
{'Device1': [['Device1', 'TenGigabitEthernet1/0/11', 'SHUT', '', '', 'IDF03', '#f76f6f'], ['Device1', 'TenGigabitEthernet1/0/12', 'SHUT', '', '', 'IDF03', '']],
 'Device2': [['Device2', 'TenGigabitEthernet1/0/11', 'SHUT', '', '', 'IDF03', '#f76f6f'], ['Device2', 'TenGigabitEthernet1/0/12', 'SHUT', '', '', 'IDF03', '']]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Just found out that the ports are getting sorted like this: /1,/10,11,.....,2,20,21,...,3,31,32....is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Convert the `Port` column to integer type. I modified my answer~

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
with open("data-dic.txt", 'r') as dic:
    data = json.load(dic)
    d2 = OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x:int(x[1][0][1].rsplit('/', 1)[-1])))
    print(d2)
```

Sorting based on the `value.first_row.second_element.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]`

NB:
`dataDic = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(dataDic))` This line of code doing absolutely nothing. You change `dict -> str -> dict`. And it's not a good practice to use `ast.literal_eval` to parse the JSON.

Comment: Suggestion: `x[1][0][1].split('/')[-1]` => `x[1][0][1].rsplit('/', 1)[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict comprehension and sort sublist by index.

```
output = {k: sorted(data.get(k), key=lambda x: x[1].split("/", 2)[-1]) for k in data.keys()}
print(output)

{'Device1': [['Device1', 'TenGigabitEthernet1/0/11', 'SHUT', '', '', 'IDF03', '#f76f6f'], ['Device1', 'TenGigabitEthernet1/0/12', 'SHUT', '', '', 'IDF03']], 'Device2': [['Device2', 'TenGigabitEthernet1/0/11', 'SHUT', '', '', 'IDF03', '#f76f6f'], ['Device2', 'TenGigabitEthernet1/0/12', 'SHUT', '', '', 'IDF03']]}
```